# Safe use of a function that writes data after a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function `foo(void* buffer, size_t len)` that calculates a hash from the data at `buffer` (of size `len`) and appends it at the end of `buffer`.

Usually I have a vector that I would pass to `foo(&myVec[0], myVec.size())`

How would I safely use this function with a vector? Resize it before passing it?

```
void foo(void* buffer, size_t len)
{
 if(buffer == NULL)
 { 
  printf("Error\n");
  return;
 }
 std::vector<unsigned char> hash(128);
 gethash(buffer, len, &hash[0]);
 unsigned char *data = ((unsigned char*) buffer) + len;
 memcpy(data, &hash[0], hash.size());

}
```

Comment: Your `foo` has a really unintuitive interface prone to programmer error resulting in a buffer overflow. I recommend you change it to accept an additional pointer to a buffer for the result and possibly another size argument.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the vector is a `vector<char>`, you could avoid all the messyness and do:

```
 void foo(vector<char>& buffer)
 {
      std::vector<unsigned char> hash(128);
      gethash(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), hash.data());
      buffer.resize(buffer.size()+hash.size();
      unsigned char *data = buffer.data() + buffer.size();
      memcpy(data, hash.data(), hash.size());
 }
```

This is still a bit "messy", but a lot less than the code you posted.

As suggested in the comments, something like:

```
     buffer.insert(buffer.end(), hash.begin(), hash.end());
```

is probably better than the last three lines I wrote.

Comment: `std::copy(hash.begin(), hash.end(), std::back_inserter(buffer));`

Comment: How about just `buffer.insert(buffer.end(), hash.begin(), hash.end());` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it!

If `buffer`points to memory with given `len` you can't reallocate more memory at exact this place.

2 ways to deal with it:

The buffer comes already with enough size for data and hash, but I would prefer a struct for this solution!

or

Allocate new memory, copy data and hash value to it and return the pointer the new data memory. But don't forget to free this memory later and also the input memory.

The second solution can be done with a vector

```
void foo( vector<char> &vec )
{
...
    gethash(&vec[0], len, &hash[0]);
...

    vec.resize(...);  // reallocate and copy data if needed
    memcpy // which I do not want to use with a vector :-)

}
```

A resize of a vector results in allocating new memory and copy data from old to new memory and free the old buffer allocated. It is possible that the vector holds (much) more memory as expected so that no reallocation must happen. But how it behaves must not be known until speed is a criteria. But you can also create a vector with a minimum of internal size so that you prevent automatic allocation and copy.

Comment: Thanks for the two solutions! How about passing a vector instead of pointer and length, which I would then `.resize()` within the function?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. But this is in fact the second solution. The vector itself holds the pointer to any kind of memory. A resize will allocate and copy if needed. Simply that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this before calling `foo`:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> buffer;
    size_t sz = buffer.size();
    size_t tsz = sizeof(decltype(buffer)::value_type);
    buffer.resize(128 /  tsz + buffer.size());
    foo(buffer.data(), sz * tsz);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
void foo(vector<unsigned char>& data)
{
    if(data.empty())
        return;

    vector<unsigned char> result(128);
    gethash(&data[0], data.size(), &result[0]);
    data.insert(data.end(), result.begin(), result.end());
}
```